# Loop on rows produced by SELECT - looping variable does not exist?

Tags: postgresql, loops, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, ddl

The function is created fine, but when I try to execute it, I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR: relation "column1" does not exist
> SQL state: 42P01
> Context: SQL statement "ALTER TABLE COLUMN1 ADD COLUMN locationZM geography (POINTZM, 4326)"
> PL/pgSQL function addlocationzm() line 6 at SQL statement
> ```

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addlocationZM() 
RETURNS void AS
$$
    DECLARE
        COLUMN1 RECORD;
    BEGIN
        FOR COLUMN1 IN SELECT f_table_name FROM *schema*.geography_columns WHERE type LIKE 'Point%' LOOP
            ALTER TABLE COLUMN1 ADD COLUMN locationZM geography (POINTZM, 4326); 
        END LOOP;
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

SELECT addlocationZM()
```

I'm probably just being dumb, but I've been at this for a while now and I just can't get it. The `SELECT f_table_name ...` statement executed on its own returns 58 rows of a single column, each of which is the name of a table in my schema. The idea of this is to create a new column, type PointZM, in each table pulled by the SELECT.

Comment: [Executing Dynamic Commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Comment: @Abelisto Thanks, now I just have to figure out how to get around a missing quote_ident( record ) function. I hate using outdated Postgres

Comment: Probably `format('%I', COLUMN1.f_table_name)`?

Comment: Or just `quote_ident(COLUMN1.f_table_name)`

Comment: @Abelisto I didn't try format(), but quote_ident() worked perfectly, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function would work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addlocationZM() 
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _tbl text;
BEGIN
   FOR _tbl IN
      SELECT f_table_name FROM myschema.geography_columns WHERE type LIKE 'Point%'
   LOOP
      EXECUTE
      format('ALTER TABLE %I ADD COLUMN location_zm geography(POINTZM, 4326)', _tbl); 
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note how I use a simple `text` variable to simplify matters. You don't need the `record` to begin with.

If it's a **one-time operation**, use a `DO` command instead of creating a function:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
      SELECT string_agg(
                format(
                   'ALTER TABLE %I ADD COLUMN location_zm geography(POINTZM, 4326);'
                  , f_table_name)
              , E'\n')
      FROM   myschema.geography_columns
      WHERE  type LIKE 'Point%'
      );
END
$do$;
```

This is concatenating a single string comprised of all commands (separated with `;`) for a single `EXECUTE`.

**Or**, especially while you are not familiar with plpgsql and dynamic SQL, just generate the commands, copy/paste the result and execute as 2nd step:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE '
     || quote_ident(f_table_name)
     || ' ADD COLUMN locationZM geography(POINTZM, 4326);'
FROM   myschema.geography_columns
WHERE  type LIKE 'Point%';
```

(Demonstrating `quote_ident()` this time.)

Related:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

Aside: Unquoted CaMeL-case identifiers like `locationZM` or your function name `addlocationZM` may not be such a good idea:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Comment: Wow, awesome answer. Didn't realize I could just skip straight to text. Thanks for the help!